# ESP32 debugging over serial port from VSCode?

Tags: esp32, vscode-debugger, esp-idf

I'm developing firmware on a custom board and would like breakpoints and step-through debugging. I can't retroactively fit JTAG.

What's the best way to add breakpoint debugging in VSCode on Windows? I print general logs to the serial port and would like to retain that, if possible. The application is freertos-based. I've tried OpenOCD in the past but I don't at all find anything in VSCode intuitive, so need a bit of a "for-dummies" hand-holding here.

Currently printing logs to serial, it's effective only to a point...

Answer (score 0):

The ESP32 requires a JTAG connection (and an adapter, e.g. [ESP-Prog](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/espressif-esp-iot-solution/en/latest/hw-reference/ESP-Prog_guide.html)) for debugging.

Comment: ESP32-S3 and ESP32-C3 have a built-in JTAG adapter.